# Showing error when getting data from first activity using intent.getStringExtra

Tags: java

```
package com.example.onlinefoodordermobileapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //public void DisplayMenu(View view){
    //    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Menu.class);
    //    startActivity(intent);
    //}
    public void PlaceOrder(View view){
        public final static String MSG = "ORDER";
        EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText editText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String message = editText1.getText()+", "
                        +editText2.getText()+" and "
                        + editText3.getText()+" added to Cart";
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,placeOrder.class);
        intent.putExtra(MSG,message.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is my first activity

```
package com.example.onlinefoodordermobileapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class placeOrder extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MSG);
        TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

This is my second activity

IT is giving error on intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MSG) on "MSG". I don't know why. In first activity it is also giving error on public static final String MSG = "ORDER"; on "public" and "static"
I don't know why.

Comment: The line: `public final static String MSG = "ORDER";` needs to be outside the method  `PlaceOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

The line: public final static String MSG = "ORDER"; needs to be outside the method

```
package com.example.onlinefoodordermobileapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String MSG = "ORDER";

//public void DisplayMenu(View view){
//    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Menu.class);
//    startActivity(intent);
//}
public void PlaceOrder(View view){
    
    EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText editText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String message = editText1.getText()+", "
                    +editText2.getText()+" and "
                    + editText3.getText()+" added to Cart";
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,placeOrder.class);
    intent.putExtra(MSG,message.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Like this